# How to change an image using an array in xcode (objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, xcode

So I'm new Objective C and I'm building my first app, although I'm stuck on a particular function for my character creation feature.

I have added 'back' & 'forward' buttons and these are meant to move between the selections that I have (e.g. shirt images).

I have 4 different choices for the shirt and was wondering how I would add these 4 images into an array that I would then be able to use with the 'back' and 'forward' buttons in order to navigate between the choices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: xcode is not a programming language: it is a tool that is used to build iOS and OS X programs. To answer your question, you need to tell us which programming language you are using. Please add the appropriate tag. (I am guessing Swift, but you need to tell us.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Swift or Objective-C? I'll assume Objective-C. Ok. So you got it. Now you just got to implement it. You'll have to initialize a new array with the four images, `arrayWithObjects:` or `initWithObjects:`. You'll have to have a `UIImageView` drawn on the screen, added as a subview (`UIView's addSubview:`). Then you may want to keep  a disposable "counter" private **ivar** (could be a property too if you wanted) that keeps track of the index of the current image being displayed (declared in your .m, .h is fine too). You could do this **or** you could have a dynamic getter method that returns the index based on the method `objectAtIndex:` on your array with your image view's image. When the user clicks forward or back the counter is updated (if it's an ivar and not a getter) and the image view's image is updated based on the new counter value (eg. `self.imageView.image = imageArray[counter]`) or something like that. You could disable the forward/back buttons if the counter value is on the edge of the array's `count` property. When the view is initially loaded you could load the image view's image based on the current counter value which would be `0` by default.

In this answer, I did not write the code for you. I showed you snippets of stuff and gave you different potential alternatives to write your program. You'll have to put it together yourself and choose what you're most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I can make of your response:)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, there are two classes of objects: Primitives (like `NSInteger`, `int`, `char`) and everything else. Non primitives can be stored in `NSArray`s. `NSArray`s are immutable, meaning that you cannot change them once they have been created. However, there is a sub-class of `NSArray`s called `NSMutableArray`. You can add and delete objects to these and sort them if you want. So if you have four 
`UIImage` objects, you could do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* images = [NSMutableArray new]; 
[images addObject:image1];
[images addObject:image2]; 
[images addObject:image3]; 
[images addObject:image4]; 
....
```

The objects are added in order, so you can retrieve the second image (for example) like this:

```
UIImage* second = [images objectAtIndex:1];
```

(Indexing is zero-based)

Comment: There's no reason to make it mutable. You can just initialize the array with the images.

Comment: Yes, assuming that you have the objects available when you initialize the arrays. But sometimes you don't. In any case, the other answer showed "initWithObjects" so I wanted to show the alternative.

Comment: But in this case, am I not adding several objects? My intention was to change one image into several others.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean about changing one image into several. Change how?

Comment: I've added one UIImageView to the storyboard and this has the value "img_shirt3.png" in the image section. I intend to create an array that stores all the images (img_shirt2.png, img_shirt3.png, img_shirt6.png and img_shirt7.png)... then by using both the next and previous buttons, they will cycle through the images... Would I maybe need a counter that operates +1 when I hit 'next' and -1 when I hit previous... corresponding these values to the images in the array?

Comment: you got it. Make sure you test the edge cases. You can use the image property of UIImageView to change the visible image.